# How to select max amount dates from table

Tags: mysql

I have two columns in a table, first is a date with hour (ex. 2014-07-14 21:00) in the datetime format, the second is an amount.

I am looking for a way to return the peak amount per day with its date & time.

```
SELECT datetime,MAX(EarlySessSetupSuccCtr) 
FROM netact_15min.cscflcc_pcscf WHERE datetime >= (now() - interval 5 day) 
GROUP BY day(datetime)
```

This will always return the time of 00:00 even though the peak amount occurred at a different hour.

Comment: How is your date column set up?  Is it DATETIME?  If it doesn't actually contain a TIME it will always default to 00:00:00.

Comment: have you tried CURDATE() instead of NOW()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self join on same table by matching day and max amount from sub select to the amount stored in table

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM  netact_15min.cscflcc_pcscf t
JOIN (
SELECT DAY(`datetime`) `day`,MAX(EarlySessSetupSuccCtr) max_amount
FROM netact_15min.cscflcc_pcscf 
WHERE `datetime` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY  `day`
) t1
ON(t1.`day` = DAY(t.`datetime`) AND t.EarlySessSetupSuccCtr = t1.max_amount)
```

Note it can give morethan one results per day if there are two records with max amounts on that specific day

Answer (score 0):

without some data I can't test this.. but I believe this will do what you want.

```
SELECT DATE(datetime), MAX(EarlySessSetupSuccCtr) 
FROM netact_15min.cscflcc_pcscf 
WHERE DATE(datetime) >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 day) 
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

basically strip out the time portion... compare the date of your datetime column to the last 5 dates.. and then group by that date. should fix your problem